# Laravel count unique database value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, unique, distinct

I need to perform counting functionality:

- The User can download only 5 files (total) per 24 hours. For example: User has 5 available downloads today, User downloaded myFile1.txt file and now he has 4 available downloads today, but if he wants to download myFile1.txt file again, he can do it as many times as he wants (still 4 available downloads), but if he downloaded new file myFile2.txt, now he has 3 available downloads.

My question, how to track, how many times a User downloaded a file.
This is my code:

```
    /*
      * $id {string} = file name;
      * $dayStart (Timestamp) = example: 2020-03-25 00:00:00;
      * $dayEnd (Timestamp) = example: 2020-03-26 00:00:00;
      * $total (int) = how much User has downloaded;
      * $response = file download functionality.
      * auth()->user()->dailyDownloads (int) = default value 5.
    */
    public function downloadFile(Request $request, $id){
      $file = storage_path('app/files/') . $id .'.bin';

      // Tracking operation date, find all records in this date interval.
      $dayStart = Carbon::today();
      $dayEnd = Carbon::tomorrow();
      $total = DumpDownloadHistory::distinct('dataset')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->
                      whereBetween('created_at', [$dayStart, $dayEnd])->count();

      $findIfDownloaded = DumpDownloadHistory::distinct('dataset')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('dataset', $id)->count();


      if ($total >= auth()->user()->dailyDownloads) {
        dd('To many downloads');
      }

      if (file_exists($file)) {
          $headers = [
              'Content-Type' => 'application/bin'
          ];

        $response = response()->download($file, $id.'.bin', $headers, 'inline');
        if ($response) {
          // Storing download history to Database
          auth()->user()->downloadHistorys()->create([
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'dataset' => $id,
            'user_ip'=> request()->ip()
          ]);
          return $response;

        }
      } else {
          abort(404, 'File not found!');
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel secure bin files download with limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60833160/laravel-secure-bin-files-download-with-limitations)

Comment: No, I try to count database row without duplication.